# AngularJS : Protractor : How to retrieve content of nested ng-repeat tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am newbie to Protractor testing tool for AngularJS. I have following code that I want to test it using Protractor

**HTML Part**

```
<table>
     <tr ng-repeat="row in rowcolumnsetup" id="{{$index}}">
         <td ng-repeat="column in rowcolumnsetup" id="{{$index}}" ng- 
                style="getClass($parent.$index,$index)"></td> 
     </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var targetByRow = [[]];

//Setup Target Row

for(var row = 0 ; row < 7 ; row++) {
  targetByRow[row] = [7];

  for(var column = 0 ; column < 7 ; column++) {
    targetByRow[row][column] = {
            class : "",
            Status : ""
    };
  }
}

$scope.rowcolumnsetup = targetByRow;
```

Now in *spec.js* in Protractor, I want to check whether, `rowcolumnsetup` has any value in class or status field. So in order to access `rowcolumnsetup`, I am able to get row but unable to figure out about how to retrieve column

```
element.all(by.repeater('row in rowcolumnsetup')).then(function(rows) {
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    // Work in progress to retrieve column
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you want to give the attribute value of `ng-style` to class field? and What value you want to give to status field?

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableData = element.all(by.repeater('row in rowcolumnsetup')).map(function(row) {
  var tds = row.all(by.css('td'));

  return {
     // give ng-style value of first td cell to class
     class: tds.get(0).getAttribute('ng-style'),
     // assume give the text of first td cell to status
     status: tds.get(0).getText()
  };
});

tableData.then(function(datas){
  //datas[0].class  ng-style value of first cell in first row
})
```